# How to disable or ignore background screen's touch events after loading an overlay?

Tags: flame

In flutter flame, after tapping on pause button on score overlay at the top, I pause the game engine, and display a little pause overlay window at the center of the screen, but score overlay which is visible in the background still is tappable. I want to disable all the touch events behind pause overlay window. I couldn't find a workaround using AbsorbPointer and IgnorePointer Widgets.

1. Disable underlying tap events behind active overlay?
   or
2. Dismissing the overlay window by tapping outside of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some talk about this situation [here](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/issues/1734).

What you could do is add a `GestureDetector` that covers the full screen in your overlay, something like this:

```dart
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  onTap: () {
    ...
  },
  child: <<Your current overlay>>,
);
```

Comment: hi @spydon, how about the same situation when RouterComponent is being used instead of Overlays? Your inputs would be much appreciated.

Comment: @srv_sud you should be able to set transparent = false for the route that you are adding with the RouterComponent

Comment: Thanks for the response @spydon. I have tried that option but it alters my UI where I need the underneth route to be still partially visible but not receive the tap events.
For now I have used a work around by checking the current router against eh name of the Router in which the onTapUp has been implementd. eg. 

  void onResumeTapUp() {
    if(gameRef.router.currentRoute.name == RouteNames.PauseRoute) {
      // do your stuff ..
    }
  }